# How do I achieve 2 level tabs?

Tags: 6, routes

Drupal 6 had an easy way to do this, but D7 doesn't.
I asked this question on the drupal.org forums, and I didn't get answer. Am I asking too much? I just want 2 level tabbed main menu where I can have full control over the link styling.

Bottom line, I want to extract each individual link (and sub link) from the main menu and theme them individually.

Comment: How were you doing this in Drupal 6 (tabs is a bit ambiguous--are you talking tabs as on a node page, or primary/secondary navigation behavior)? Specifying which method you used may help clarify what you are trying to do in Drupal 7, and why it isn't working.

Comment: I used the primary secondary menus in druapl 6 to accomplish this, most of the drupal 6 themes (including the default ones) recognized this method and appropriately showed the sub links.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a theme that supports the output of primary and secondary links in the way you describe (Bartik, the default theme for Drupal 7 does, but it doesn't have the secondary nav below the primary, but rather in the upper right of the header), you can accomplish this by setting the secondary menu to be the same as the main menu. Navigate to admin/build/menu/settings to make this selection.

You can further customize this behavior using the [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module.